# How can I organize case-insensitive text and the material following it?

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python so it'd  be very appreciated if this could be explained as in-depth as possible.

If I have some text like this on a text file:

```
matthew : 60 kg
MaTtHew : 5 feet
mAttheW : 20 years old
maTThEw : student
MaTTHEW : dog owner
```

How can I make a piece of code that can write something like...

```
Matthew : 60 kg , 5 feet , 20 years old , student , dog owner
```

...by only gathering information from the text file?

Comment: new to just python or new to programming? I ask because that would change my answer

Comment: How far have you gotten on your own? Reading a file? Splitting it on  newlines? Splitting a line on a colon character? Lowercasing the left value?

Comment: new to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def test_data():
    # This is obviously the source data as a multi-line string constant.
    source = \
    """
matthew : 60 kg
MaTtHew : 5 feet
mAttheW : 20 years old
maTThEw : student
MaTTHEW : dog owner
bob : 70 kg
BoB : 6 ft
    """

    # Split on newline. This will return a list of lines like ["matthew : 60 kg", "MaTtHew : 5 feet", etc]
    return source.split("\n")

def append_pair(d, p):
    k, v = p
    if k in d:
        d[k] = d[k] + [v]
    else:
        d[k] = [v]
    return d


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Do a list comprehension. For every line in the test data, split by ":", strip off leading/trailing whitespace,
    # and convert to lowercase. This will yield lists of lists.
    # This is mostly a list of key/value size-2-lists
    pairs = [[x.strip().lower() for x in line.split(":", 2)] for line in test_data()]
    # Filter the lists in the main list that do not have a size of 2. This will yield a list of key/value pairs like:
    # [["matthew", "60 kg"], ["matthew", "5 feet"], etc]
    cleaned_pairs = [p for p in pairs if len(p) == 2]
    # This will iterate the list of key/value pairs and send each to append_pair, which will either append to
    # an existing key, or create a new key.
    d = reduce(append_pair, cleaned_pairs, {})    
    # Now, just print out the resulting dictionary.
    for k, v in d.items():
        print("{}: {}".format(k, ", ".join(v)))
```

Comment: Probably best to explain what this does

Comment: that would be very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

# There's a number of assumptions I have to make based on your description. 
# I'll try to point those out. 

# Should be self-explanatory. something like: "C:\Users\yourname\yourfile" 
path_to_file = "put_your_path_here"

# open a file for reading. The 'r' indicates read-only 
infile = open(path_to_file, 'r')

# reads in the file line by line and strips the "invisible" endline character
readLines = [line.strip() for line in infile]

# make sure we close the file
infile.close()

# An Associative array. Does not use normal numerical indexing. 
# instead, in our case, we'll use a string(the name) to index into. 
# At a given name index(AKA key) we'll save the attributes about that person. 
names = dict()

# iterate through each line we read in from the file
# each line in this loop will be stored in the variable
# item for that iteration. 
for item in readLines:

    #assuming that your file has a strict format: 
    # name : attribute
    index = item.find(':')

    # if there was a ':' found then continue
    if index is not -1:
        # grab only the name of the person and convert the string to all lowercase
        name = item[0:index].lower()
        # see if our associative array already has that peson
        if names.has_key(name): 
            # if that person has already been indexed add the new attribute
            # this assumes there are no dupilcates so I don't check for them.
            names[name].append(item[index+1:len(item)])
        else:
            # if that person was not in the array then add them. 
            # we're adding a list at that index to store their attributes.
            names[name] = list()
            # append the attribute to the list. 
            # the len() function tells us how long the string 'item' is
            # offsetting the index by 1 so we don't capture the ':'
            names[name].append(item[index+1:len(item)])
    else: 
        # there was no ':' found in the line so skip it
        pass

# iterate through keys (names) we found. 
for name in names:
    # write it to stdout. I am using this because the "print" built-in to python
    # always ends with a new line. This way I can print the name and then 
    # iterate through the attributes associated with them
    sys.stdout.write(name + " : ")
    # iterate through attributes
    for attribute in names[name]:
        sys.stdout.write(attribute + ", ")

    # end each person with a new line.
    sys.stdout.write('\r\n')
```